# deleting data in java application but it is still displayed in jtable

Tags: java, sql, database, swing, jtable

i have written a java application with tables and functions like add,delete or update.

My problem is, that I delete a row in the table and it is deleted in the database, but when I click on a free space of my JTable the deleted row appears again?

here my  code:

**DAO CLASS**

```
@Override
public void delete(int id) throws SQLException {

    handle = new DatabaseHandler();
    con = handle.buildConnectionToServer();
    query = "DELETE FROM Team WHERE TID="+id;
    std = con.createStatement();
    std.execute(query);
    con.commit();
    handle.closeConnection();
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
//ActionListener "Delete" Button in "DeleteEquipment"
            public void controllActionListenerDeleteEquipmentSubmit(){
                main.setActionListenerDeleteEquipmentSubmit(new ActionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                        if(arg0.getSource()==main.getDeleteEquipment()){
                            EquipmentDAO equipment = new EquipmentDAO ();

                            int a = (int)main.getDeleteEquipmentPanel().getDeleteValues().getValueAt(main.getDeleteValues().getSelectedRow(),0);
                                try {
                                    equipment.delete(a);
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully Deleted");
                                    equipmentArr = equipment.show();
                                    main.getDeleteEquipmentPanel().showAllDelete(equipmentArr);
                                    equipmentArr=null;
                                } catch (SQLException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

**MAINFRAME**

```
//Back Button of "DeleteEquipment" to "ManageEquipment"
        public void setActionListenerBackDeleteEquipment(ActionListener actionListener) {
            deleteEquipment.getDeleteEquipmentBack().addActionListener(actionListener);
        }
        public JButton getDeleteEquipmentBack(){
            return deleteEquipment.getDeleteEquipmentBack();
        }

    //Delete Button in DeleteEquipment
        public void setActionListenerDeleteEquipmentSubmit(ActionListener actionListener) {
            deleteEquipment.getDeleteEquipment().addActionListener(actionListener);
        }
        public JButton getDeleteEquipment(){
            return deleteEquipment.getDeleteEquipment();
        }
```

Comment: Reload the data from the database and update the `TableModel` or remove the content from the `TableModel` once you've successfully deleted the rows from the database...